# Read only two-dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, immutability, readonly

Is there any established way of returning a read-only 2-d array in C#?

I know `ReadOnlyCollection` is the right thing to use for a 1-d array, and am happy to write my own wrapper class that implements a `this[] {get}`. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel if this wheel already exists.

Comment: there's nothing built in for multidimensional arrays afaik

Comment: Here are some answers from a similar question on StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net

Comment: That's not very similar, @Scorpion-Prince.

Comment: Perhaps a ReadOnlyCollection, each of whose elements is also a ReadOnlyCollection?

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince: and Op's says that he is aware that can implement kind of wrapper.

Comment: @KirkWoll it's a little bit similar.

Comment: @MarkReed That would be easy for a jagged array.  For a non-jagged array copying the data wouldn't be as trivial.

Comment: @MarkReed that would be more trouble to implement than it's worth ... unless sblom is asking about a 2-d jagged array.  I had assumed he meant a proper 2-d array, like `T[,]` rather than `T[][]`.

Comment: Yes, more like `T[,]` than `T[][]`, although it isn't a _huge_ deal for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one way to simulate this.

You need to create your own class, with a private array.

The most similar implementation of an array is an indexer:

- [Using indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)
- [Indexers (C# programming guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)
- [10.8 Indexers (old)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103002717/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664459(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [C# 6.0 draft Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#indexers)

The '10.8' link shows the simulation of a bidimensional array.

If you implement the indexer only with a getter, the user can only read the elements, but not write them. However, if each element is an object (reference type) you can't prevent the modification of the accessed objects properties.

However, there are several ways of simulating "read-only" objects:

- Create a wrapper class that exposes the properties of each element in the array as read only properties, so that they cannot be modified
- Using primitive value types (like `int`)
- Defeating the changes by returning a copy of the element in the private array instead of the original element in the private array, so that, the changes made to the object don't affect the original object in the array.

In other languages like C++ there are references and pointers to constant values, but this doesn't exist in C#.

Comment: The 10.8 link is broken. Here it is on the wayback machine:https://web.archive.org/web/20120103002717/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664459(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no any built-in implementation to handle a case you ask for.
But a simple implementation on your own, shouldn't be something difficult.

The only think, I hope you aware of it, that you will do is a readonly *collection*, but *not* elements inside that collection.

Hope this helps.