# Can variables of type IEventAggregator (or) Dictionary made 'readonly'?

Tags: c#, resharper, readonly

I am currently doing a C# code review using **ReSharper**. This Code has been written targeting .NET 4.0 framework.

My question here is can we use the modifier '*readonly*' on a *IEventAggregator* (or) *Dictionary* variable type(s) while declaring it? I have been suggested far too many times to do this by ReSharper.

I did go through this post *[Is there a read-only generic dictionary available in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net)*, but it doesnt discuss about using the modifier '*readonly*'. Kindly assist.

Comment: The keyword `readonly` doesn't make the instance readonly, it makes the *reference* to the instance readonly so that you cannot assign the reference to some other instance of an object or null. For example: `private readonly List<int> numbers;` doesn't stop `numbers` from being mutated, it stops you from assigning something else into the `numbers` reference once it has been assigned from the constructor.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I'd argue that it *does* stop `numbers` from being mutated, because `numbers` is a variable. It stops "the object that the value of `numbers` refers to" from being mutated. I'd also say it makes the *variable* read-only rather than the reference. The reference is just a value; references themselves can't be changed anyway. A non-readonly variable can have its value changed though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, I struggle to find the correct terminology to express the idea. However, I'm sticking with the mutability statement. A mutable item can be stored in a readonly variable. You can add and remove `int`s from my example, for example, that to me is mutating the list.

Comment: @JonSkeet Come to think of it, yes I've confused the comment by stating `numbers` is mutable, but that is saying the variable is mutable, which it won't be. The list referred to by the variable will be mutable, which is what I was trying and failing to say all along. This is why I don't write books on the subject ;-) I know it in my head, I just can't explain it lol

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth though I am little confused understanding the nuances of your explanation I think I got the core point. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it? Thanks.

Comment: btwn I think I sould modify my question as 'variable of type Dictionary or IEventAggregator' instead of *instance*. making that change now

Comment: @ranjith No need, Jon has provided an answer. It'll be more clearly written than whatever I can come up with :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects of mutability in this line (as an example):

```
private readonly List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

The `names` variable is read-only. You can't change its value (other than in the constructor). So if you had a method like this:

```
public void ResetNames(List<string> newNames)
{
    names = newNames; // Error!
}
```

That wouldn't compile. So that's the *variable*.

Next, consider the object that the variable's value refers to - in this case, a `List<T>`. That *object* is mutable... you can change the data within it. So this is fine:

```
public void AddName(string name)
{
    names.Add(name);
}
```

Now some types (e.g. `string`) are themselves immutable - so you can't modify the data in the object either. It gets more complicated than just those two extremes though. For example, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is immutable in that you can't do anything *to that object* to mutate it (which means you're safe to expose it to callers, for example), but it can wrap a collection which is itself mutable:

```
List<string> mutable = new List<string>();
ReadOnlyCollection<string> funky = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(mutable);
Console.WriteLine(funky.Count); // 0
mutable.Add("xyz");
Console.WriteLine(funky.Count); // 1
```

There are more kinds of immutability than that, even - see [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) for more, for example.

The main thing is that you need to differentiate between the *variable* being readonly, and the *object that it refers to* being immutable. They are very different.