# const Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, immutability, readonly

I have a class in C# that contains a Dictionary, which I want to create and ensure nothing as added, edited or removed from this dictionary as long as the class which contains it exists.

readonly doesn't really help, once I tested and saw that I can add items after. Just for instance, I created an example:

```
public class DictContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary;

    public DictContainer()
    {
        myDictionary = GetDictionary();
    }

    private Dictionary<int, int> GetDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        myDictionary.Add(1, 2);
        myDictionary.Add(2, 4);
        myDictionary.Add(3, 6);

        return myDictionary;
    }

    public void Add(int key, int value)
    {
        myDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

}
```

I want the Add method not to work. If possible, I want it not to even compile. Any suggestions?

Actually, I'm worried for it is code that will be open for a lot of people to change. So, even if I hide the Add method, it will be possible for someone to "innocently" create a method which add a key, or remove another. I want people to look and know they shouldn't change the dictionary in any ways. Just like I have with a const variable.

Comment: Strange requirements suggest your design has issues.  You might want to rethink what you're attempting here.  Otherwise, you can easily create your own implementation that does this.

Comment: You can implement your own Dictionary. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002/does-c-have-a-way-of-giving-me-an-immutable-dictionary

Answer (score 8):

Hide the Dictionary totally.  Just provide a get method on the DictContainer class that retrieves items from the dictionary.

```
public class DictContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary;

    public DictContainer()
    {
        myDictionary = GetDictionary();
    }

    private Dictionary<int, int> GetDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        myDictionary.Add(1, 2);
        myDictionary.Add(2, 4);
        myDictionary.Add(3, 6);

        return myDictionary;
    }

    public this[int key]
    {
        return myDictionary[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't define the `Add` Method.

Keep the `myDictionary` variable private and expose a Getter/Indexer so that it can only be read from outside that class..

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do that, consider using [a wrapper class.](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=29)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IReadOnlyDic<Key, Value>
{
    void Add(Key key, Value value);
}
class ReadOnlyDic<Key, Value> : Dictionary<Key, Value>, IReadOnlyDic<Key, Value>
{
    public new void Add(Key key, Value value)
    {
        //throw an exception or do nothing
    }
    #region IReadOnlyDic<Key,Value> Members

    void IReadOnlyDic<Key, Value>.Add(Key key, Value value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

to add custom items;

```
    IReadOnlyDic<int, int> dict = myDictInstance as IReadOnlyDic<int, int>;
    if (dict != null)
        dict.Add(1, 155);
```

Answer (score 0):

and this is another way

```
class ReadOnlyDic<Key, Value> : Dictionary<Key, Value>
{
    private bool _locked = false;

    public new void Add(Key key, Value value)
    {
        if (!_locked)
        {
            base.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ReadOnlyException();
        }
    }
    public void Lock()
    {
        _locked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of the solution, and for compatibility with the Dictionary's interfaces. However: Why using "new" instead of "override"? Further, besides the Add, the Remove method should be overridden, too.

Comment: @chiccodoro: `Dictionary` does not have `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, now it is built-in to .net 4.5.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853776):

Hide the Dictionary totally.  Just provide a get method on the DictContainer class that retrieves items from the dictionary. If you want to use [] override you need getter settter method (atleast any one get/set)

```
public class DictContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary;

    public DictContainer()
    {
        myDictionary = GetDictionary();
    }

    private Dictionary<int, int> GetDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        myDictionary.Add(1, 2);
        myDictionary.Add(2, 4);
        myDictionary.Add(3, 6);

        return myDictionary;
    }

    public this[int key]
    {
        get => myDictionary[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: @cigien I have changed the function to make it work =>  public this[int key]
    {
        get => myDictionary[key];
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to make edits to your answer to clarify something, please go ahead.