# How to properly use IReadOnlyDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, readonly-collection

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548.aspx):

> Represents a generic read-only collection of key/value pairs.

However consider following:

```
class Test
{
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "1", "111" },
        { "2", "222" },
        { "3", "333" },
    };

    public IReadOnlyList<string> List { get; } =
        (new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" }).AsReadOnly();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();

        var dictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)test.Dictionary; // possible
        dictionary.Add("4", "444"); // possible
        dictionary.Remove("3"); // possible

        var list = (List<string>)test.List; // impossible
        list.Add("4"); // impossible
        list.RemoveAt(0); // impossible
    }
}
```

I can easily cast `IReadOnlyDictionary` to `Dictionary` (anyone can) and change it, while `List` has nice `AsReadOnly` method.

Question: how to properly use `IReadOnlyDictionary` to make public indeed **read-only** dictionary ?

Comment: I think creating an *Adapter* over the `Dictionary` can help to expose only the **read-only** behaviour.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what an interface does. It just describes a contract. `IList<T>` could inherit `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, for example, but that doesn't make the list implementing `List<T>` read-only. Is your actual question _"How can I make a read-only dictionary"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster, hmm, yes. But not *making* it myself, rather reuse existing in .net type properly.

Comment: @adricadar, I am using properties.

Comment: Those interfaces were poorly named. This one should have been called IReadableDictionary. Its contract defines readability but says nothing about whether it's writable or not, and its name should have done the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

.NET 4.5 introduced the [`ReadOnlyDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) type that you could use. It has a constructor that accepts an existing dictionary.

When targeting lower framework versions, use the wrapper as explained in [Is there a read-only generic dictionary available in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net) and [Does C# have a way of giving me an immutable Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002/does-c-sharp-have-a-way-of-giving-me-an-immutable-dictionary).

Please note that when using the latter class, the collection initializer syntax won't work; that gets compiled to `Add()` calls.

Comment: Didn't noticed `ReadOnlyDictionary` (it's well hidden), thanks. I can use normal `Dictionary` with collection initializer as a constructor parameter for `ReadOnlyDictionary`.

Comment: You could also use [`ImmutableDictionary<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) if you're using the latest version of .Net. (That's a hardcore immutable class ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, good to know, thanks. I wonder what is a difference, but that would be another question, right?

Comment: @Sinatr `ImmutableDictionary<>` is not a wrapper class and it is truely immutable,. `ReadOnlyDictionary` is only a wrapper and it's important to note that if you change the contents of the wrapped dictionary, the contents of the read-only dictionary also change. It's read-only, not immutable!

Comment: @MatthewWatson, thanks for explanation. I am not going to change dictionary content after creating instance (writable dictionary instance is not stored and `ReadOnlyDictionary.Dictionary` property is `protected`), so *read-only* is all I need. The idea with `ToBuilder() / ToImmutable()` is nice (multithreading?), might use `ImmutableDictionary` some day.