# Make dictionary read only in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, covariance

I have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and would like to expose the member as read only. I see that I can return it as a `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<string>>`, but I can't figure out how to return it as an `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>>`.

Is there a way to do this? In c++ I'd just be using const, but C# doesn't have that.

Note that simply using a `IReadOnlyDictionary` does not help in this case, because I want the values to be read only as well. It appears the only way to do this is build another IReadOnlyDictionary, and add IReadOnlyList to them.

Another option, which I wouldn't be thrilled with, would be to create wrapper which implements the interface IReadOnlyDictionary>, and have it hold a copy of the original instance, but that seems overkill.

Comment: What about a lookup instead? The Dictionary object has the `ToLookup()` extension. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly use IReadOnlyDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560619/how-to-properly-use-ireadonlydictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a read-only generic dictionary available in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net)

Answer (score 41):

It would be as easy as casting the whole dictionary reference to `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>>` because `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

BTW, you can't do that because you want the `List<string>` values as `IReadOnlyList<string>`.

So you need something like this:

```
var readOnlyDict = (IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>>)dict
                        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.AsReadOnly());
```

### Immutable dictionaries

This is just a suggestion, but if you're looking for immutable dictionaries, add [`System.Collections.Immutable` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) to your solution and you'll be able to use them:

```
// ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<string>>
var immutableDict = dict
           .ToImmutableDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.ToImmutableList());
```

Learn more about [Immutable Collections here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time/).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Thanks! Immutables are powerful and learning them is worth the effort. Read-only collections aren't immutable, and OP has said "I want something like constants..."

Comment: Won't "ToDictionary", create a copy of the whole dictionary?

Comment: @bpeikes Yes, and you need to do this way because you can't cast the list to read-only list with an explicit or implicit cast.

Comment: you can cast to IReadOnlyDictionary but it can be casted back to Dictionary and modify the dictionary as the instance itself hasn't changed.

Answer (score 10):

Given the fact that you're specifically looking for a read-only `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, you're basically looking exactly for a [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx).

The Dictionary object has a `ToLookup()` extension.

Comment: Not exactly. Reading the Remarks section of a Lookup class: `A Lookup<TKey,TElement> resembles a Dictionary<TKey,TValue>. The difference is that a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> maps keys to single values, whereas a Lookup<TKey,TElement> maps keys to collections of values.`

Comment: Yes, @MladenB., but the OP asked for the value to be a `List<string>`, so the lookup works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same problem. I solved it on the following way.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<string>>();

IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<string>> dicRo = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<string>>(dic);

 list.Add("Test1");

 dic["T"] = list.AsReadOnly();

 ist.Add("Test2");
```

This has the positiv effekt, that you

- can still add items to the list
- can still add items to the dictionary
- can't edit the ReadOnlyDictionary
- can't edit the ReadOnlyCollection
- can't cast it into a Dictionary
- can't cast it into a List
- have your ReadOnlyDictionary always up to date

Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll have to create a new dictionary with the desired content types:

```
var dicWithReadOnlyList = dic.ToDictionary(
    kv => kv.Key,
    kv => kv.Value.AsReadOnly());
```

Then you can just return the new dictionary, since `IReadOnlyDictionary` is a supertype of `Dictionary`.

---

Why do you need to do that? Because `Dictionary<T, A>` is not a supertype of `Dictionary<T, B>`, *even if* `A` is a supertype of `B`. Why? Consider the following example:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<T, B>();
Dictionary<T, A> dic2 = dic;      // Imagine this were possible...

dic2.Add(someT, someA);           // ...then we'd have a type violation here, since
                                  // dic2 = dic requires some B as the value.
```

In other words, `TValue` in `Dictionary` [is not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149589/87698). From an object-orientied point of view, covariance *should* be possible in the read-only version of the dictionary, but there are legacy issues in the .NET framework which prevent this  (see the part starting with "UPDATE" in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149589/87698) for details).

Comment: Well it's just because `TValue` can't be covariant, but on this case I believe that `List<string>` is `IReadOnlyList<string>`. It's not exactly `A` and `B`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: How is that different? If A is a supertype of B, B is A.

Comment: `Dictionary` wouldn't need to be covariant with respect to `TValue`, **`IReadOnlyDictionary` would need to be covariant with respect to `TValue`.

Comment: @Servy: True, that would be OK from an OO point of view. Unfortunately, there seem to be legacy issues in the framework which prevent that (see the [lower half of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant) for an explanation).

Comment: @Heinzi That's `IDictionary`, not `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

Comment: @Servy: When I said **the lower half** of the question, i meant the part starting with "UPDATE". To quote: *"There will be an `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in .NET 4.5, but it won't be covariant either :·/, because it derives from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, and `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is not an interface and thus cannot be covariant."*

Comment: @Downvoter: Feedback to improve the answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering the question, but [.NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#performance-focused-types) introduces [FrozenDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozendictionary-2?view=net-8.0).

The new `System.Collections.Frozen` namespace includes the collection types `FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue>` and `FrozenSet<T>`. These types don't allow any changes to keys and values once a collection is created. That requirement allows faster read operations (for example, `TryGetValue()`). These types are particularly useful for collections that are populated on first use and then persisted for the duration of a long-lived service, for example:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a read only dictionary but still be able to mutate the dictionary and list in your class you could use casting to get back the list type.

This example is a bit contrived, but shows how it could work.

```
public class MyClass
{
    Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>> _dictionary;
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>> Dictionary { get { return _dictionary; } }

    public MyClass()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<string>>();
    }

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<string> readOnlyList = null;
        List<string> list = null;
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out readOnlyList))
        {
            list = new List<string>();
            _dictionary.Add(item, list);
        }
        else
            list = readOnlyList as List<string>;
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

If you goal is to have the property be immutable, then using a ReadOnlyDictionary would be the best option.

Answer (score -2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

You can use this to expose the object as readonly.

You could also use properties get; set; and only allow the get to be public.

But Matias answer seems to be more fitting.

Comment: readonly complex types like dictionaries can still be changed by using methods like `.Add()` or `.Remove()`