# Difference between ReadOnlyDictionary and Lookup in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, lookup, readonly-collection

I'm still learning much about immutability and when to use such objects and have started incorporating more [Lookups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) into my coding for the fact that I knew them to be immutable and, hence, often better to use than Dictionaries that could be changed by clients.

That being said, I know there has been a good deal of work on introducing [ReadOnlyDictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) into .Net and I'm a bit confused where each would be more useful than the other and what specifically makes them different. I've looked online, but can't seem to find any articles explaining this difference.

For example, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39086520/1693085) and figured a Lookup would be a more ideal solution, but am confused as to why it wouldn't be.

Can anyone point me in the right direction / explain where either would be used over the other.

Thanks!!

Comment: Lookup is a mapping of a key to multiple values, whereas a dictionary is a key to one value. Not related to immutability, but they aren't exactly the same data structure.

Comment: It sounds like you want to know why to make it readonly? The answer is the same for anything that should not be changed by an outside or private actor, ie. why make something/anything readonly. It is not specific to a dictionary and I would say its really an opinionated question.

Comment: I'm more confused as to why there even is a ReadOnlyDictionary when it seems a lookup is basically already performing that job.

Comment: Can you post a link to this `Lookups` type you are referring to?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer whats the point of lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1403499/1260204) or [this answer dictionary vs. lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5659080/1260204) ? One difference is a lookup is allowed to have multiple values per key, a dictionary cant.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor, I guess what I'm wondering also is, in terms of immutability, would a lookup be in any way worse to use (more possibility of mutability) than a ReadOnlyDictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookups are an easy way to group collections, where you could have one *or* *more* values for a given key.  A Dictionary gives you *one* value for a give key, and one value only.  Depending on your scenario, it may make most sense to have a Dictionary where you get back *one* value, or you may want to have a Lookup which would give you a collection of values.

Without a Lookup if you wanted a collection of values for a certain key you'd be stuck with something ugly like

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<String>>
```

Yuk.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more on Lookups.

Comment: Thanks, but in terms of immutability, would a lookup be in any way worse to use (more possibility of mutability)  than a ReadOnlyDictionary?

Comment: @JohnBustos What the answer is trying to say is a `ILookup<TKey, TValue>` is just a more friendly way to create a `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>`

Comment: Thanks so much @ScottChamberlain, that's what I was hoping was the outcome!!